# JAXB library: there is no text content for the XML type associated with this class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I get this error "There is no text content for the XML type associated with this class. JAXB Problem" in the automatic generated class from XSD. Do you know what's happening?

*Source code*

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "linkType", propOrder = {
    "content"
})
public class LinkType {
    @XmlValue **THIS LINE HAS THE ERROR**
    protected String content;
```

*XSD*

```
<xs:complexType name="linkType" mixed="true">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            The Atom link construct is defined in section 3.4 of the format spec.
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:attribute name="href" use="required" type="xs:anyURI"/>
    <xs:attribute name="rel" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="type" use="optional" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="hreflang" use="optional" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
    <xs:attribute name="title" use="optional" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="length" use="optional" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="atom:commonAttributes"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

BR.

Comment: Try to generate a xml to compare with the xsd to understand what is content? I do not think JAXB can generate a variable which is not defined in your XSD.

Comment: I did it and the result class seems to be correct. In fact, in another PC the same workspace doesn't get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you are seeing is an Eclipse validation exception:

> There is no text content for the XML type associated with this class.

You can ignore this exception as it is an editor exception and not a compiler exception:

Comment: I have tried to use a lower version of Eclipse (Indigo instead of Juno) and now I don't get this error, so I supposed you are right and it is only an exception of the editor. Thanks.